# How to Delete in MS SQL WHERE IN (SELECT Multiple Columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table lets call it "`Cluster`" which is related an second table `Element`

Cluster:

```
Id Group Ele1 Ele2 Ele3
1   1     1    2     3
2   1     4   NULL   9
3   2     5    8     7
```

Element

```
Id Name
1  'A'
2  'b'
3  'c'
4  'd'
5  'z'
6  'j'
7  't'
8  'r'
9  'e'
```

now i have to delete an Cluster

```
DELETE FROM Cluster
WHERE   Cluster.Group= 1
```

but before i delete the rows from my `Cluster` i need to delete all related rows from `Element`

```
DELETE FROM Element
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Ele1 Ele2 Ele3 
             FROM Cluster 
             WHERE Cluster.Group= 1)
```

but this query doesn't work  so what do i miss?

Comment: @Woot4Moo means i know the `IN (...)` part is wrong because IN is only for single columns but it was the easiest way to show what i want without writing to mutch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compact and clean :

```
DELETE FROM Element
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT
        Ele
    FROM Cluster AS T
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (T.Ele1)
        , (T.Ele2)
        , (T.Ele3)
    ) AS X (Ele)
    WHERE T.Group= 1
)
```

Comment: @WilMaxx Group might need to be put between brackets (you gave us a sample where you didn't use brackets).

Comment: ah that is interesting (i don't know why i should use brackets). Looks like you are the winner here but let me ask you something to your query  why do you write  `AS X (Ele)` instead of `AS Ele` is that something special? also the ` AS T`part does it some improvements i doesn't see?

Comment: X is the "table" alias name, Ele is the column name. Both are of course mandatory for the query to run.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM Element
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Ele1
             FROM Cluster 
             WHERE Cluster.[Group] = 1
                   And Ele1 Is Not NULL

             Union 

             SELECT Ele2
             FROM Cluster 
             WHERE Cluster.[Group] = 1
                   And Ele2 Is Not NULL

             Union 

             SELECT Ele3 
             FROM Cluster 
             WHERE Cluster.[Group] = 1
                   And Ele3 Is Not NULL
)
```

Comment: so i can't deny calling select multiple times?

Comment: @WiiMaxx you can use unpivot

Comment: You COULD join to the cluster table and put all three comparisons in one where clause, but that would not be as clear as this solution, and a join in a delete statement has other problems.  I would put the un-pivot of the table by the unions in it own view if it is used frequently.  A Pivot may be another solution, but it may have performance impacts... I'd stick with the union.

Comment: @Rawheiser mhh i don't wane write this part 7 times (thats my actual nummber of Columns) accordingly to the rule don't repeat yourself

Comment: "Don't repeat yourself" is a good rule, but a GREAT rule would be "normalize your data". Store all the repeated columns of data in its own table - and then you could do a singular select.

Comment: @Rawheiser but this normalization would be an big overhead :) because each Row in Cluster will be mapped to an Column for an Table(Group) with unknown Column size but known Row size so each Ele is a refernce to an Cell in my Table an Element is the object which is stored in this Cell so i don't think it will be more easier with more Tables also i doesn't really know how you would build the relations between them but if you want you can show it to my in an Fiddle. maybe i learn something new :) , like everyday :D

Comment: Speaking of "Don't repeat yourself"... that is exactly what you are doing with your un-normalized table.  It may be more work up front to modify your design, but it will likely pay off in the long run.

Comment: NOrmalize your data if you want to be able to qwuery it properly. This design is bad, it needs to befixed before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

```
delete  from Element
where ID in
(
SELECT Item
   FROM 
      (SELECT [Group], Ele1, cast([Ele2] as int) Ele2, Ele3 FROM Cluster) p
   UNPIVOT(Item FOR Ele IN (Ele1, Ele2, Ele3) )AS unpvt
  )
```

Comment: you miss the `WHERE Group=1` part :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of working solutions but I don't see any explanation as to why they work and your attempt fails.

The `IN` operator wants a list of values to check. At its simplest it looks like `WHERE column IN (value1, value2, value3...)`. It also works with a `SELECT` list: `WHERE column IN (SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable)`.

Your query doesn't return a single column which can be used as a list, but three different columns. This is incorrect syntax for the IN operator. G Mastros's solution uses the UNION operator to combine three different select queries in one, single column, result set.

(Incedentally, I would use `UNION ALL` in this case since duplicated values aren't an issue and `UNION` is a slower operation. But check your client statistics as checking multiple copies of the values may be more of a performance drain than `UNION`)

StuffHappens is using the `UNPIVOT`operator to get the same behaviour of splitting the three required columns into a single result set. Personally, I'd go with `UNION`, mainly because I find the `UNPIVOT` syntax harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the table to not have multiple columns is the best answer.

G Mastro's answer is a good given your existing table design.

How it would look normalized ... so you could just do:

```
delete from Element 
where Id in ( select EleId from  GroupElements where Group_id = 1 )


*Cluster* 

Id Group
1   1   
2   1   
3   2   

*GroupElements*

Group_id EleId
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   9
2   5
2   8
2   7


*Element*

Id Name
1  'A'
2  'b'
3  'c'
4  'd'
5  'z'
6  'j'
7  't'
8  'r'
9  'e'
```

Comment: so how would you normalize this table?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Element
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Ele1
         FROM Cluster 
         WHERE Cluster.Group= 1) AND Id IN (SELECT Ele2
         FROM Cluster 
         WHERE Cluster.Group= 1) AND Id IN (SELECT Ele3
         FROM Cluster 
         WHERE Cluster.Group= 1)
```

Comment: Does not work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37d64/8/0 (compare with the result from Mastros answer).

Comment: Those ANDs look like they should be ORs.

Answer (score -1):

You're not selecting the ID column from Cluster in the subquery.  Try:

```
DELETE FROM Element
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id 
         FROM Cluster 
         WHERE Cluster.Group= 1)
```

Comment: @Joe i don't think you get what i want ^^

Comment: Explain?  The subquery will return all IDs from Cluster with a Group of 1.  The records from Element with an Id in that subquery will be deleted.

Comment: ok let me explain it this way `Cluster` and `Element` have a Multiple `1:1` Relationship`. `Cluster.Ele1` to `Element.Id`, `Cluster.Ele2` to `Element.Id`, ...